# Finding the maximum area of a triangle with a perimeter constrain

Tags: geometry, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Using graphical methods, determine the dimensions of a right triangle that
has the largest possible area, given that the perimeter cannot be larger than
$P$. The final answer should be in terms of $P$.

I got the equation 
max $$\frac{1}2 xy$$
s.t.
   $$ x + y + \sqrt{ x ^2 + y^2} \leq P$$

Comment: Please show your work. It is not different from a rectangle problem. Area could be  for 45 deg right triangle.

Comment: I suppose that the optimal solution has perimeter equal to $P$, because otherwise by homothety one could derive a contradiction.

Comment: yes I believe that is true

Comment: The answer would depend on what kind of "graphical methods" are acceptable to whoever asked the question. I suggest you think about what graphical methods you have seen already, try to apply some of them, and edit the question to show what you found and where you got stuck (if you did not find the answer already).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $z$ is the hypotenuse, then $\frac12xy=\frac14(P^2-2Pz)$, so you need the right triangle with minimum hypotenuse. Now show $(x+y)^2\le 2z^2$ or otherwise conclude this happens when the triangle is isosceles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a triangle with constant perimeter (12 units):

[image]

Observe how the function of area changes.